# Reoccurring Event Series: Sheets to Calendar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a newbie when it comes to coding, so lots to learn from my end. I created the following script which would integrate reoccurring Office Hours from data pulled from Sheets to Calendar. I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do this? How would I be able to include a For Loop for this, since most of them reoccur on different days of the week?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
function officeHoursEventSeries() {
var spreadsheet =          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var lr = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("d2").getValue();
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
//for 1
var title1 = spreadsheet.getRange("a4").getValue();
var start1 = spreadsheet.getRange("b4").getValue();
var end1 = spreadsheet.getRange("c4").getValue();
var descrip1 = spreadsheet.getRange("d4").getValue();
var reccurence1 = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeekday(CalendarApp.Weekday.TUESDAY).until(new Date('December 21,2021'));
cal.createEventSeries(title1,start1,end1,reccurence1,{description: descrip1})

//for 2
var title2 = spreadsheet.getRange("a5").getValue();
var start2 = spreadsheet.getRange("b5").getValue();
var end2 = spreadsheet.getRange("c5").getValue();
var descrip2 = spreadsheet.getRange("d5").getValue();
var reccurence2 = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeekday(CalendarApp.Weekday.FRIDAY).until(new Date('December 21,2021'));
cal.createEventSeries(title2,start2,end2,reccurence2,{description: descrip2})

//for 3
var title3 = spreadsheet.getRange("a6").getValue();
var start3 = spreadsheet.getRange("b6").getValue();
var end3 = spreadsheet.getRange("c6").getValue();
var descrip3 = spreadsheet.getRange("d6").getValue();
var reccurence3 = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeekdays([CalendarApp.Weekday.MONDAY,CalendarApp.Weekday.WEDNESDAY]).until(new Date('December 21,2021'));
cal.createEventSeries(title3,start3,end3,reccurence3,{description: descrip3})

//for 4
var title4 = spreadsheet.getRange("a7").getValue();
var start4 = spreadsheet.getRange("b7").getValue();
var end4 = spreadsheet.getRange("c7").getValue();
var descrip4 = spreadsheet.getRange("d7").getValue();
var reccurence4 = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeekday(CalendarApp.Weekday.TUESDAY).until(new Date('December 21,2021'));
cal.createEventSeries(title4,start4,end4,reccurence4,{description: descrip4})

//for 5
var title5 = spreadsheet.getRange("a8").getValue();
var start5 = spreadsheet.getRange("b8").getValue();
var end5 = spreadsheet.getRange("c8").getValue();
var descrip5 = spreadsheet.getRange("d8").getValue();
var reccurence5 = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeekdays([CalendarApp.Weekday.TUESDAY,CalendarApp.Weekday.THURSDAY]).until(new Date('December 21,2021'));
cal.createEventSeries(title5,start5,end5,reccurence5,{description: descrip5})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('a4:d8').getValues().forEach(r => {
  let title = r[0];
  let start = r[1];
  let end = r[2];
  let descrip = r[4];
  //I'll leave recurrence up to you to figure out
  cal.createEventSeries(title, start, end, reccurence, { description: descrip });
})
```